# getting the particular field from array

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot

i knew its simple question but still,

```
List<User> role = findUserRole(user.getManager());
```

getting below data

```
[ User 
  [  id=null,
     email=null, 
     password=null, 
     mailID=null, 
     firstName=null, 
     middleName=null, 
     lastName=null, 
     roles= [
        Role [
          id=5c78f8a11cfcb83a2848b714, 
          role=GROUPHEAD
          ]
      ]
  ]
]
```

how to get particular field value for above array, and that is like.

```
 role=GROUPHEAD
```

How to get this in java,

Comment: What is `findUserRole(xxx)`? What does return `user.getManager()` ?

Comment: calling method to get above data. @lvr123 ...this data is store in role variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `List<User> userList = findUserRole(user.getManager());` gives the `userList` object, which is a list, you can get the respective `User` object if you know the index (otherwise you need to iterate with a foreach loop and get the required user with the id), by:

```
User requiredUser = userList.get(index);
```

Then you get the `List<Role>` by:

```
List<Role> roleList = requiredUser.getRoles;
```

From there you get the required role field if you know the index (otherwise you need to iterate with a foreach loop and get the required role with the id) by:

```
String role = roleList.get(index);
```

So to summarize, you can get the role field (if you know the right indices, otherwise you need to use foreach loop) by:

```
String role = findUserRole(user.getManager()).get(userIndex).getRoles.get(roleIndex);
```

Comment: @Mark-VII Did this help you?